# Recursive integration with array - Stefan Boltzmann law

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot Stefan Boltzmann law via integrating Planck law. When I set one temperature, say T=3000, the code produces its integration well. However, when I make T as array like np.array([310,3000,5800,15000]), the code gives me errors. Attached image is a plot that I am trying to reproduce. Anyone who have insights to solve this problem, it would be very appreciable. Thank you in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

h = 6.626e-34
c = 2.9979e+8
k = 1.38e-23
T=np.array([310,3000,5800,15000])

from scipy.integrate import quad
def integrand(wav):
    return (2.0*3.14*h*c**2)/ ( ((wav*1e3*1e-9)**5) * (np.exp(h*c/(wav*1e3*1e-9*k*T)) - 1.0) )*1e-6

power, err = quad(integrand, 0.01, 100)
print(power)
```

[image: Stefan Boltzmann law by Methamatica]

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the equation for several Temperatures at once? Not sure if this makes any sense, rather do it for each temperature separately.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the calculation at once. Trying to avoid a long code. ie. repeating...I'm a new Python learner, if you can write the code in a more elegant way, please, let me know. Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: My initial plan was once I get numbers of integration, then interpolate to produce the SB law plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do the integration for each temperature separately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

h = 6.626e-34
c = 2.9979e+8
k = 1.38e-23
temps=np.linspace(300,15000)


def integrand(wav,T):
    return (2.0*3.14*h*c**2)/ ( ((wav*1e3*1e-9)**5) * (np.exp(h*c/(wav*1e3*1e-9*k*T)) - 1.0) )*1e-6

p = lambda T: quad(integrand, 0.1, 100, args=(T,))[0]

powers = list(map(p, temps))
plt.plot(temps, powers)
plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
plt.ylabel("Power")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. I learned from your expertise.